# Is there an overhead because of nesting Futures

Tags: scala

I wrote this code

```
package com.abhi
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureNesting extends App {

   def measure(future: => Future[Unit]) : Future[Long] = {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val ec = implicitly[ExecutionContext]
      val t = future
      t map { case _ =>
         val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
         end - start
      }
   }

   measure(Future{ Thread.sleep(10000) }) onSuccess {case a => println(a)}
   scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
}
```

So how many threads am I using in this code. The broader question is that what is the impact of going on nesting future inside futures.

So I ran the application above and observed it using Visual VM. This is what I saw

[image]

So the application launched 2 threads ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5 and ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3. However it launches the same 2 threads even if I remove the nesting. So I am not sure what is the overhead because of nesting the futures like above.

Edit:: Some people said it depends on the type of ThreadPool (ForkJoin etc).

I won't know what type of pool do Akka.HTTP or Spray use? I planned to use a code snippet similar to the one above in a Spray web service. The idea was to measure the performance of the web service using Futures.

Comment: depends on your hardware architecture

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are using wrap over thradpool (ForkJoingPool from java.util.concurrent). Of course, all Futures are executed in it.

```
 import scala.concurrent.ExecutionConext.Implicits.global
```

Based on this you must implicitly instantiate pool instead import, like this:

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext
```

And use method from ForkJoinPool: `getActiveThreadCount()`

Second approach:
You can open profiler (like JProfiler - from Jetbrains or Jvisualvm - attached with jdk) and watch meta information including threads parameters like their amount, activity, memory usage and etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and edited my code above. I can get access to the ExecutionContext but can't call getActiveThreadCount on it.